# Python - can you plot a histogram with a contour?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, draw

I want to plot a histogram with a contour like this [image]

I found this picture in [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.05-histograms-and-binnings.html), but after following the same procedure there I don't get the contour.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741687/python-histogram-outline) question in stack overflow but it draws an edge over each bar, and I want only the outer contour.

How can I draw this outer contour? (I'm running python 3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plot is probably produced with a different (i.e. older) matplotlib version. This can also be seen from the use of `normed`, which is deprecated in newer versions.

Here, you would explicitely set the edgecolor to black. 
`ec="k"`, or longer, `edgecolor="black"`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

x1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.8, 1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(-2, 1, 1000)
x3 = np.random.normal(3, 2, 1000)

kwargs = dict(histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, density=True, bins=40, ec="k")

plt.hist(x1, **kwargs)
plt.hist(x2, **kwargs)
plt.hist(x3, **kwargs);

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the `alpha` only affect the filling and not the contour?

Comment: @ThomasAhle, you can add another histogram over the semitransparent one with ```histtype='step'```. But I'm also interested if it can be done in one line of code.